# InDesign: Can tags add behavior to xml?

Tags: indesign-scripting, xml

I have an xml file and a template. For some reason when I import the xml it ads a blank element between the title and subhead. The element doesn't exist in the xml file, but before I import it there is a tag and a paragraph style for this element.

Is there a way to have a tag cause different behaviors to imported xml files? If so, where would I go to edit that?

Comment: Do you have it set to ignore white space? If not, it will import line breaks between the XML elements as paragraph breaks.

Comment: I want them to import line breaks between the elements, but its also creating a new element after the first. For example the xml is "<title><head><paragraph>" But when I import it I get "<title><sign><head><paragraph>" I don't know where this sign is getting created from.

Comment: Perhaps you have a tag associated with the style (in “Map Styles to Tags”) that’s been there from a previous import? I suppose that might conceivably add an extra element to match the style…